# Render Razor code in JS fuction after the document has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

```
$("body").on("click", "#ActionButton", function (e) {
            //set current select index
            currentBook = $(this).attr("data-bookId");
            //set title

            $("#BookAction .modal-title").text('@Model[currentBook].BookName');
            //get list of current book forms
            @{List<XLEZ.Models.DataModels.FormModel> CurrentFormsList = Model[currentBook].FormList;}


            swap('FillNewData', true);// collapse fill new data list if expanded
            $("#FillNewData").empty();
            @for (int k = 0; k < CurrentFormsList.Count; k++)
            {<text>
            var html = "<li onClick=\"SubmitForm('@CurrentFormsList[k].FormLink','@CurrentFormsList[k].FormHideExtraValue','@Model[currentBook].FormActionLink')\" class=\"list-group-item bg-grey-300\" > @Html.Raw(CurrentFormsList[k].FormName) </li>";
            $(html).appendTo("#FillNewData");</text>
            }

        });
```

i am using above code to submit a form by using data in Model. The problem is that I want to do it after the page has been loaded and user makes a selection. But the razor code renders before document is ready and when i click on this button the data on 0 index of model is loaded in this script. Is there anyway i can loop through the model in this function?

Comment: You can't pass JavaScript variable to Razor server side code.

Comment: @Satpal: Any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to pass/convert JavaScript variable to a Razor variable. *Razor variable is handled by Razor engine* where as *JavaScript on the other hand is a client side language running on the client.*

Razor is a view engine used by the ASP.NET MVC framework running on the server to produce some HTML template.

However, You can use [**Json.Encode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) Method converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format. Then perform your operation using it.

```
//Convert Model to JSON 
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); 

$("body").on("click", "#ActionButton", function (e) {
    //set current select index
    currentBook = $(this).attr("data-bookId");
    //set title

    $("#BookAction .modal-title").text(model[currentBook].BookName);

    //get list of current book forms
    var currentFormsList = model[currentBook].FormList;

    // collapse fill new data list if expanded
    swap('FillNewData', true);
    $("#FillNewData").empty();  

    for (int k = 0; k < currentFormsList.length; k++)
    {
        //Create link
        $('<li />')
            .addClass("SubmitForm list-group-item bg-grey-300")
            .data('FormLink', currentFormsList[k].FormLink)
            .data('FormHideExtraValue', currentFormsList[k].FormHideExtraValue)
            .data('FormActionLink', model[currentBook].FormActionLink)
            .html(currentFormsList[k].FormName)
            .appendTo("#FillNewData");
    }
});

$("#FillNewData").on('click', 'li.SubmitForm', function(){
    SubmitForm(
        $(this).data('FormLink'),
        $(this).data('FormHideExtraValue'),
        $(this).data('FormActionLink'),
    )
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought of doing same thing, the model have many images in base64 and a lot of textual data, Converting it to json is a good idea ? keeping the nature of model in view.

Comment: Personally, I would not like to persist images in json data however for textual data its fine. Other way I would recommend is the usage of partial view generated using an action